# Silverlight Sync

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, asynchronous

I try to right a method which result is boolean for **custom validation** in a model!

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(SpecialValidator), "IsUniQueCountryCode")]
```

It must be sync so the method can have a result value:

```
    public static ValidationResult IsUniQueCountryCode(string value) {
    if (value.Length > 0)
    {
        DSCountry _context = new DSCountry();
        ObservableCollection<MCountry> List = new ObservableCollection<MCountry>();
        LoadOperation<Country> loadOp = _context.Load((_context.GetCountryByCodeQuery(value)).Where(s => s.ISOCode == value));
        IEnumerable<Country> Entities;
        bool test = false;      
        loadOp.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            test = true;
        };

        //
        if (test == true)
        {
        }
        //
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

How can I make the load **synchronous**?

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight doesn't support synchronous service calls. So unless you want to use really ugly hacks (see link below), you need to pre-load that information when the application starts or find a way to rewrite it in an asynchronous fashion.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SynchronousSilverlight.aspx

Oh, and validation routines should be really, really fast. They may be called at any time, often for no apparent reason, so making a service call inside them is a bad idea.